# Error CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME when I use cl_khr_fp64 in a kernel

Tags: opencl

I have an error in an **OpenCL** kernel, when I try to use the **cl_khr_fp64** extension, the kernel compiles and the build log is empty, but when I call `clCreateKernel`, I have **CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME** error.

The source that fails:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

__kernel void simple( __global char *x, __global char *y ){
int id = get_global_id(0);
y[id]=2*x[id];
}
```

This source compiles right:

```
__kernel void simple( __global char *x, __global char *y ){
int id = get_global_id(0);
y[id]=2*x[id];
}
```

I'm using **OpenCL 1.0** with a **Tesla C1060** that have **cl_khr_fp64** in **CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS**, driver 280.13 and **CL_PLATFORM_VERSION**=OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 4.0.1

Comment: Just to clarify - you know that your compilation succeeds in the first case because you are checking the error code set by clBuildProgram, correct?

Comment: Compilation steps returns CL_SUCCESS, but I also check the build log

Comment: Are you saying that if you simply remove the cl_khr_fp64 line, clCreateKernel returns CL_SUCCESS?

Comment: I think Zhen is saying that compilation succeeds in both cases, but when he calls `clCreateKernel(..., "simple", ...)` in the first case, he gets `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME`.  The second case succeeds.  Zhen, is this your situation?

Comment: thats the case @James. Both examples compiles, but with cl_khr_fp64 I get CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME on clCreateKernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that before call to clCreateProgramWithSource, we remove the newlines from source. E.g: the source:

```
"__kernel void f( __global char *x ){\nint id = get_global_id(0);\nx[id]=2;\n}"
```

Becomes:

```
"__kernel void simple( __global char *x, __global char *y ){"
"int id = get_global_id(0);"
"x[id]=2;}"
```

It causes no problem until we add the preproccessor directive.

It's the OpenCL preprocessor which actually wants newlines to be there. So, it should be written as:

```
"__kernel void simple( __global char *x, __global char *y ){\n"
"int id = get_global_id(0);\n"
"x[id]=2;}\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the very things that has been bugging me. The problem I think is the previously compiled code is cached somewhere and being reused. So your new changes give weird errors.

To fix it (NOT a "real solution" but it works for me) try changing your program name (and kernel name, maybe) e.g. if program is a.out then next time you compile make it a2.out and see if it is fixed. I hope this helps.

if you find a better solution please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I also came cross such bug a few days ago and I just work it out. So I'm here sharing my solution although it's quite wired and I still don't know why.

```
static inline void CreateOCLKernels()
{
    std::cout << "ocl lowlevelengine: Creating ocl kernels ...\n";
    filterSubsample_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "filterSubsampleUChar4Kernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel0");
    filterSubsampleWithHoles_float4_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "filterSubsampleWithHolesFloat4Kernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel1");
    filterSubsampleWithHoles_float_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "filterSubsampleWithHolesFloatKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel2");
    gradientX_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "gradientXKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel3");
    gradientY_ocl_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "gradientYKernel", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel4");
    //type-dependent ocl memset kernels
    memset_ocl_kernel_Vector4s = clCreateKernel(program, "memsetKernelVector4s", &clError);
    checkErr(clError, "clCreateKernel5");
}
```

This is my original code which is a static function called by a constructor of some class. The constructor can be called without any question. However, each time the above function is called, I would received the bug "invalid kernel name" resulting from opencl cannot find the kernel "filterSubsampleUChar4Kernel".
I've tried a lot but none of them worked. But today, very occasionally, I try to change the function name and I succeed. **What I do is nothing more than change "filterSubsampleUChar4Kernel" to "filterSubsampleKernel".** I also tried to change other names, eg. "filterSubsampleKernel_test", "filterSubsample1Kernel". But they didn't work. It's quite wired, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you write OpenCL code using string. such as

```
std::string code =
"#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable"
"__kernel void simple( __global char *x, __global char *y )"
"{"
"int id = get_global_id(0);"
"y[id]=2*x[id];"
"}"
```

just add "**\n**" at the end of **#pragma** line

```
std::string code =
"#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable\n"
"__kernel void simple( __global char *x, __global char *y )"
"{"
"int id = get_global_id(0);"
"y[id]=2*x[id];"
"}"
```